# Table of contents looks bad with package chngcntr

Tags: table-of-contents, chngcntr

I'm using the package "chngcntr" to restart the chapter count in each part of my work. It's working just fine. However, in the table of contents, the chapters and all other sections numbers overlap the text. It's look awful. Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Thank you,

Pedro

Comment: `chngcntr` has nothing to do with the TOC. Are you refering to the numbers being too long? Which class are you using? Are you using `tocloft`? In general, please post example code such that we get a better picture of what your document look like. Otherwise it is very hard to help as the help will depend on many issues.

Comment: Yes, the numbers are too long. I'm not using tocloft. Just have \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
and the class is report

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, could you provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7853/toc-text-numbers-alignment/7856#7856 helps.

Comment: Also have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/how-to-modify-the-indentation-before-sectioning-titles-in-the-table-of-contents