# Awful ToC layout, while using roman number

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, roman-numerals, roman

I use the article class.

I want a ToC and pages with roman number, so I use the following :

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
```

But the ToC layout is horrible (while page title are great) :
[image]

Any help, please?

*For the record, I'm using latex since two month and I did great until this problem, which i can't solve by myself.
I did a research over the web but I can't find anything about this.*

Comment: Welcome to the site! Does [TOC Text - numbers alignment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7856) help? (Note that if you're using the `memoir` class you don't have to load the `tocloft` package.)

Comment: Is there any special reason you want to use Roman numbering when mentioning your A9 operating system?

Comment: My temporary solution is to use the report class instead of the article class. I will keep trying with tocloft package like  Torbjørn T suggested. And I'm sorry Brent but i don't understand what do you mean by "A9 operating system"?

Comment: Not sure if @Brent.Longborough is joking or not. If not, [AIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX).

Comment: @MikeRenfro I was joking (if you can call it that) to make a point -- Roman numerals aren't very user-friendly. Maybe OK for numbering Parts, but only if five or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tocloft` as suggested by Torbjorn. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{3em}   %% adjust as you wish
\cftsetindents{section}{3em}{1.5em}   %% adjust as you wish
\cftsetindents{subsection}{4.5em}{2.5em}   %% adjust as you wish
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{7em}{3.5em}   %% adjust as you wish
\usepackage{blindtext}   %% for dummy text
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]