# List of figures alignment

Tags: table-of-contents

How can I align the content in the list of figures?
When I use `\listoffigures`, some characters are overlapped.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Package `tocloft`, I would say.  Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. This makes helping you much easier

Comment: An example of `tocloft` can be found in [TOC Text - numbers alignment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7856)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I see now, I have to mark this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the `A.1.1.1` labelling is too wide for the figure number width slot in the `LoF`

Use the `tocloft` package and increase the width of the figure numbers, i.e.

`\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{10pt}`

Change `10pt` to an appropiate value:

Here's a small example, the `\foreach` loops are just for quicker setup:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}

\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{10pt}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\foreach \x in {1,...,5} {
  \chapter{Chapter \thechapter}
  \section{Section }
  \subsection{Subsection }
  \subsubsection{Subsubection }
  \foreach \y in {1,...,4} {%
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{A figure with number \y}
  \end{figure}
  }
}


\end{document}
```

[image]