# TOC overlap with custom section numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I have redefined `\thesection` in my document to give me custom numbering.
Now the section number is slightly longer, and the table of contents hasn't adjusted accordingly.

In the TOC below `potatoes` overlaps `II.2`. Similarly `II.3.10` overlaps `In...`. (And the other subsections are almost overlapping, instead of having a space.)

How can I get rid of that overlap?

[image: printscreen of TOC]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel} %

\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{part}.\arabic{section}} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Fish}
\section{tuna}
\subsection{whatever} 
\subsection{canned}
\part{Vegetables}
\section{potatoes}
\section{tunips}
\subsection{This is just to use} 
\subsection{up subsections} 
\subsection{because I want to get} 
\subsection{to subsection 10} 
\subsection{because extra digits} 
\subsection{is what's causing the problem} 
\subsection{what are tunips?}
\subsection{like, who eats them?} 
\subsection{I've only ever seen them?} 
\subsection{In Howl's moving castle} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: See if e.g. [TOC Text - numbers alignment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7856) helps.

Comment: Yes, that works. (Wow that was a fast response.)

Comment: Easy to find if you know you've answered and you know the `tocloft` package was used, just a matter of searching for `user:me tocloft`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Torbjørn T in a comment above, [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7853/toc-text-numbers-alignment/7856#7856) is a solution.

(Side note: Is there a way to mark a comment as a solution, instead of writing this whole post and marking it as the solution?)

Comment: Comments cannot be marked as solutions no. The normal thing to do if a suggestion in a comment solves the problem is to ask the commenter to write an answer, but in cases like this where an identical question has been asked before and the solution given there helps, then we close the new question as a duplicate of the old one. (I've cast the first close vote already.)